# Passing a string when initialising ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, avfoundation

I'm initialising a ViewController which is supposed to be a video player view controller, the problem is that I need to pass a videoUrl String when I create it.

With this string I would actually create an AVPlayer and play the supposed video.

I don't practically know how to pass the string when initialising the viewController.

The player code is right here:

```
 let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

playerController.player = player
self.addChildViewController(playerController)
self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

player.play()
```

Comment: How do you currently initialize the view controller that contains this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how you are creating your `ViewController` instance.

**1.** If you're using the `storyboard`, then you can create a **stored property** inside `ViewController` and initialise it when creating the instance.

```
class VideoViewController: UIViewController {
    var videoUrl: String?
}
```

Now, when creating the `VideoViewController` instance,

```
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "VideoViewController") as? VideoViewController {
    vc.videoUrl = "YOUR_VIDEO_URL"
}
```

**2.** If you're not using `storyboard` and creating the `ViewController` programatically, pass the `videoUrl` inside the **`init(videoUrl:)`**

```
class VideoViewController: UIViewController {
    init(videoUrl: String?) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        //save or use videoUrl here...
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Now, when creating the `VideoViewController` instance,

```
let vc = VideoViewController(videoUrl: "YOUR_VIDEO_URL")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
 init(_ string: String) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        // use this string 
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
   }
}
```